# Importing packages errors

Tags: ibm-watson

Error in importing "from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3", and "ibm_watson" in Visual Studio Code.

Python using VS code to run the Tone Analyzer in IBM Watson cloud. I tried the existing code, however some errors occur while compiling the code, as import packaging error happen. Even the tensorflow already updated and the specific packages already installed.

The bold fonts are the errors.

`from __future__ import print_function
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
**from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_watson.tone_analyzer_v3 import ToneInput`**

`import operator
    import twitter
    import os
    import json
    **from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3**
    from _codecs import encode`

I expect there is no wrong once compiled.

Comment: What is the error and did you install the package?

Comment: These are the errors = Unable to import 'ibm_watson' , unresolved import 'ibm_watson' , Undefined variable: 'ToneAnalyzerV3' , Unable to import 'watson_developer_cloud' . already  installed  ibm_watson and ibm_watson packages.